# Setup Windows 2012 NLB with two internal servers

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, nlb

Im trying to setup a load balancing between two server on which a IIS website is running. I have a third server which actually is free to be used, i thought this one might be used to balance the load onto the first two.

All servers have only one NIC and all of them are only used internally, so no Internet, no DMZ. I just want to load balance on the two internal servers.

How do i do that with Windows 2012's NLB feature? Do i really need two NICs since i do not have internet traffic here.

I thought i can use the third server as access point where people type in the address of that server into their browsers address bar and end up on one of the NLB nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to have two NICs to set up NLB. You do not use a third server to process the requests. When you set up NLB you will assign a virtual IP address to the cluster and that will balance between the nodes.

Read more about NLB requirements here 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831698(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Ok but what is a virtual ip? Isnt this a simple host s record pointing to some real machine? How do users accessing the virtual ip get redirected to one of my node. I didn't get this part from the technet page.

Comment: You will update your sites DNS record to point to the NLB VIP instead of pointing directly to the one of the hosts.

Comment: Sorry, i still don't get it. I read about the virtual IP and its FQDN (example: abc.domain.com). The virtual IP i choose for the cluster can this be any phantasy IP? Now when some one calls abc.domain.com he ends up on the virtual IP but how the DNS know it is one of the hosts being in the cluster. This part is not explained on technet site.